# High-Availability not working in Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, high-availability

I am trying to move my non-HA namenode to HA. After setting up all the configurations for JournalNode by following the Apache Hadoop documentation, I was able to bring the namenodes up. However, the namenodes are crashing immediately and throwing the follwing error.

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: There appears to be a gap in the edit log.  We expected txid 43891997, but got txid 45321534.

I tried to recover the edit logs, initialize the shared edits etc., but nothing works. I am not sure how to fix this problem without formatting namenode since I do not want to loose any data.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanking in advance.

Comment: Have you tried starting namenode in recover mode?

    hadoop namenode -recover


Does it work well if you go back to single NN mode?

Comment: The recovery did not work. I tried resetting all the configs and did "-initializeSharedEdits" on the previous only non-HA namenode, but it threw me the following error and never got completed.                      
"java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /data/hadoop/hdfs/nn/current/edits_0000000000045188575-0000000000045188576: Too many open files". Then I also tried "-bootstrapStandby" on the newly standby namenodes and it is throwing error "gap in the edit log". I am not sure what is missing here. Any help if appreciated.

Comment: The standby nodes crashed with the following error immediately after they came up with the following error. I am not sure why they are failing to sync.     "org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.io.IOException: There appears to be a gap in the edit log.  We expected txid 45188575, but got txid 45657087."

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the limit of open files on a linux machine. I increased the limit of open files and then the initialization of shared edits worked.